# How do I draw an ellipse in 3D to match a FlyCircleAnimator in Irrlicht

Tags: 3d, irrlicht

Basically, I'm making a space game in space.

I'm generating some random solar systems. I've managed to work out how to get a nice looking solar system with planets and moons etc etc rotating and orbiting in various ellipses using FlyCircleAnimators.

What I now need is to be able to draw the path of these FlyCircleAnimators. I'm very new to the engine and to 3D in general, and I cannot work it out.

Answer (score 0):

If some object already follows desired path, you can trace it.
For example: 10 timers per second store its current absolute position in array and draw it.